# ¿Como reconectar un cliente wasync (atmosphere) cuando cae el servidor?

Tags: java, jersey, atmosphere, wasync

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto para el que debo implementar notificaciones PUSH con un servidor atmosphere. Para ello estoy utilizando un cliente wasync. En el proyecto original, se trata de un cliente Android, sin embargo he aislado tanto el código del servidor como el del cliente para aíslar la problemática.

El problema en sí, tal como indico en el título, es que cada vez que hay una caída de conexión con el servidor (por el motivo que sea), el cliente no reconecta.

**Pila de software:**

- Servidor: Atmosphere 2.4.2
- Servidor: Jersey 1.19
- Tomcat 7.0.62
- Cliente: wasync 2.1.2

Para el envío de notificaciones estoy utilizando el modelo de canales `@Subscribe` / `@Publish` proporcionado por Atmosphere. Aunque también he probado con el modelo `@Suspend` / `@Broadcast` y tampoco me ha funcionado.

**Servidor**

```
@Path("metallica")
public class MetallicaService {

    @GET
    @Path("/suscripcion")
    @Subscribe(value = "metallica", timeout = -1)
    public String handshake() {
        return null;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Publish("metallica")
    public String createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Metallica -- Track saved : " + track;
        //return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
        return result;

    }
}
```

**Cliente**

```
public class MetallicaClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final Client client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient();

        final RequestBuilder request = client.newRequestBuilder()
                .method(Request.METHOD.GET)
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/metallica/suscripcion")
                .encoder(new Encoder<String, Reader>() {        // Stream the request body
                    @Override
                    public Reader encode(String s) {
                        System.out.println("Encode: " + s);
                        return new StringReader(s);
                    }
                })
                .decoder(new Decoder<String, Reader>() {
                    @Override
                    public Reader decode(Event type, String s) {
                        if (type.equals(Event.MESSAGE)) {
                            System.out.println("---- Message received ----");
                            System.out.println("---- Date and time: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString() + " ----");
                        }
                        System.out.println("Decode: " + s);
                        return new StringReader(s);
                    }
                })
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET)                        // Try WebSocket
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.LONG_POLLING);                    // Fallback to Long-Polling

        final OptionsBuilder<DefaultOptions, DefaultOptionsBuilder> clientOptions = client.newOptionsBuilder()
                .reconnect(true)
                .reconnectAttempts(10)
                .pauseBeforeReconnectInSeconds(10);

        final Socket socket = client.create(clientOptions.build());

        try {
            socket.on("message", new Function<String>() {
                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Respuesta: " + s);
                }
            }).on(new Function<IOException>() {

                @Override
                public void on(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).on(Event.CLOSE.name(), new Function<String>() {

                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Se ha perdido la conexión con el servidor.");
                }
            }).on(Event.REOPENED.name(), new Function<String>() {

                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Reconexión.");
                }
            }).open(request.build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Del cliente me gustaría destacar el siguiente bloque de código, en el que se supone que estoy configurando la reconexión (aunque en algún punto debo estar metiendo la pata):

```
    final OptionsBuilder<DefaultOptions, DefaultOptionsBuilder> clientOptions = client.newOptionsBuilder()
            .reconnect(true)
            .reconnectAttempts(10)
            .pauseBeforeReconnectInSeconds(10);

    final Socket socket = client.create(clientOptions.build());
```

Para facilitar el trabajo, he creado un proyecto en github: https://github.com/hecnabae/jerseyAtmosphere

Answer (score 1):

Dos cosas que he visto en la documentación:

Puedes probar a crear el cliente utilizando la clase especifica para tu protocolo de la forma:

```
AtmosphereClient client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient(AtmosphereClient.class);
```

La otra cosa que he visto es que el método **reconnect(boolean)** restablece la conexión si es cerrada por el servidor, pero el método **reconnect()** hace lo mismo que el anterior y también si existe un fallo de red

No se si esto sera la solución pero es curioso que la documentación detalle la direfencia entre los dos métodos